# Unable to read in a excel XLSM file to bind to datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string

Trying to read in a XLSM file and pull data from 2 columns. I have the below code in my c# application and it doesnt seem to work, the datagridview never shows any data and when i step thru the code, i get as far as the connection string line and no errors and nothing shows.

I found a few examples of the OLE connection string to excel, but none work and the below is the latest code i tried.

Any suggestions on what im doing wrong or what else i can try?

```
        public string ConnectionString(string FileName, string Header)
    {
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToUpper() == ".XLSM")
        {
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", string.Format("Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR={0};", Header));
        }
        else
        {
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", string.Format("Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR={0};", Header));
        }

        Builder.DataSource = FileName;

        return Builder.ConnectionString;
    }

    public DataTable LoadData(string FileName)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString(FileName, "No") })
        {
            cn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText = "SELECT F2 As Parent, E2 As Gender FROM [Data$A2:I300]", Connection = cn })
            {
                OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
            }

            return dt;
        }
    }

    private void excelParents_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fn = @"C:\Temp\Template.xlsm";

        dgvParentListing.DataSource = LoadData(fn);
    }
```

At this point, im just expecting to see the data from the sheet in the datagridview control on my form. But its blank and i get no errors once the form loads

Comment: JET only works with Excel 2003 with xls files.  Will not work with xlsm.  You need to use ACE driver for xlsx.  See Connection strings : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: That got me further in the code, but nothing loads still, it get to the cmd.ExecuteReader() line and then the form opens but gridview is blank, the step thru never hits the break point on the dt.load(dr); line

Comment: Are you using IMEX=1?  Do you have any blank rows in worksheet?  Do you have data in column 1.  There are a few issues with inputting from excel.  The input is using the excel property "Used Cells".  Used cells looks at column one and sometimes will stop when column A is blank.  The IMEX = 1 option gives different results.  Make sure you set the excel version to match the version of excel that file was saved.